# Spring Swagger, hide enum constants

Tags: spring, swagger

I have `CurrencyCode`  enum which has all the currencies, using swagger how can I hide some of the currencies from being showed in the documentation?

```
public enum CurrencyCode {

    // CurrencyCodes according to ISO 4217

    @ApiModelProperty(required = false, hidden = true)
    AED, // United Arab Emirates dirham

    @ApiParam(hidden = true)
    AFN, // Afghan afghani

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
    ALL, // Albanian lek
    AMD, // Armenian dram
    ANG, // Netherlands Antillean guilder
```

I tried  `@ApiModelProperty(required = false, hidden = true)` and `@ApiParam(hidden = true)` and  `@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)` but none of them work

Comment: Define a new enum with only those values you want to show and expose that on your API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. 
Just leave the enum as it is, and in the parent class (which includes the enum) use     `allowableValues="USD,GBP,EUR"` attribute of the  `@ApiModelProperty` annotation

My full code

```
public enum CurrencyCode {

    // CurrencyCodes according to ISO 4217

    AED, // United Arab Emirates dirham
    AFN, // Afghan afghani
    ALL, // Albanian lek
    AMD, // Armenian dram
    ANG, // Netherlands Antillean guilder
    .
    .
```

and the including class

```
public class AccountInfo{

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "xxxxxxxxxx")
    @NotNull
    public final String value;

    @ApiModelProperty(allowableValues="USD,GBP,EUR", example = "EUR")
    public final CurrencyCode currency;
```

Answer (score 4):

For those using swagger annotations v3 for the following annotation can be used

```
@Schema(allowableValues = "USD,GBP,EUR", type = "String")
public enum CurrencyCode {

// CurrencyCodes according to ISO 4217

}
```

The same annotation can be applied to the AccountInfo class

```
public class AccountInfo{
    
    ...

    @Schema(allowableValues = "USD,GBP,EUR", type = "String")
    public final CurrencyCode currency;

}
```